# Why is period the same for all radii?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

I was solving this problem for centripetal acceleration:

> A computer is reading data from a rotating CD-ROM. At a point that is $0.030\ \mathrm{m}$ from the center of the disc, the centripetal acceleration is $118\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$. What is the centripetal acceleration at a point that is $0.052\ \mathrm{m}$ from the center of the disc?

So I was confused on how to do it, because I was having trouble in relating the first radius to the second radius so I went online and looked around. I found [a response from someone](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/centripetal-acceleration-of-hard-drive.292275/) stating:

> $T$ will be the same for all radii, so it is a useful thing to work with

So I tried that out and solved for $T$ using the first radius:

$$T= \frac{2πr_1}{v}$$

I got the period and then used it with the second radius

$$a_c= \frac{4π^2r_2}{T^2}$$

I solved for acceleration and got $205\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$, which seems like it is the right answer. However, I do not understand why is period the same for all radii, if in the equation:

$$T= \frac{2πr_1}{v}$$

period is dependent on the radius? wouldn't a smaller or bigger radius change this value?

Comment: Think about what it means for the disk to be a solid. What would happen if the outer radius turned at a different rate than the inner radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The period is the time it takes for a point to move around a full circle once. And for something that moves rigidly like a CD, when you turn it by one revolution, every point on the CD makes one revolution, all together. Get a disc and try this yourself: put it in the drive or on a spindle, spin it around once, and watch a point on the inner edge and a point on the outer edge. You'll see that both points make one full circle in the same time.

Comment: Never thought about it that way, got it!